# Chrome Extension: Right way of adding AngularJS controller dynamically from Content Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension using AngularJS.

I am attaching controller to required DOM elements to webpage using following content script code

```
setController() {
    if(this.setContollerCondition) {
        this.controllerElement.attr('ng-controller', 'Controller as cntrl');
    }
}
```

This method is **not always working**, as controller constructor is not getting called and 'ng-scope' is not applied to the element.

I want to ask, **what is the right method to attach a controller dynamically.**

If this method is correct, where I may be going wrong?

Following is the flow of how the activities that are happening in the Chrome extension when the page loads.

1. If ng-app is not initialised, then initialise it.
2. Initialize functions which act as event listeners
3. Check the host url, depending on the url run appropriate initialization function

   - If particular dom element is added then add customised DOM elements of extension and then Use setController() function to add the Controller to the element.

Almost all the functions are asynchronous calls.

**The behaviour currently happening is as follows**

1. The controller is set properly and works fine with a particular host which is web.whatsapp.com

   - Here all the buttons from extension are placed at proper places and work amazingly.
2. With another host, the controller is set sometimes, and sometimes not set. Host here is www.linkedin.com

   - Here The button is placed sometimes. When it is not placed, the *ng-scope* is not applied to the DOM element, as the controller constructor was not initialized.
3. With third host, the controller is never set. Host for this is mail.google.com

   - Here The button gets placed always, but the scope is not applied to the required DOM element and the constructor of Controller is not getting called.

The project uses Webpack and ES6.

Following files are similar to the actual code to help you understand the problem better.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "MyExtension",
"short_name": "MyExtension",
"omnibox": {
    "keyword": "MyExtension"
},
"description": "Description",
"version": "2.0.7",
"version_name": "2.0.7",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "128": "assets/images/icon-v2-128px.png",
        "16": "assets/images/icon-v2-16px.png",
        "48": "assets/images/icon-v2-48px.png"
    },
    "default_title": "MyExtension",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "assets/lib/angular.min.js", "assets/lib/jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "assets/lib/bootstrap.min.js", "dist/contentScript.bundle.js" ],
    "css": ["assets/css/font-awesome.min.css", "assets/css/bootstrapInject.css", "assets/css/injectingStyle.css"],
    "matches": ["*://*.linkedin.com/*", "*://web.whatsapp.com/*", "*://mail.google.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
} ],
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "contextMenus",
    "notifications",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "storage"
],
"icons": {
    "128": "assets/images/icon-v2-128px.png",
    "16": "assets/images/icon-v2-16px.png",
    "48": "assets/images/icon-v2-48px.png",
    "16": "assets/images/icon-v2-16px.png"
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "all required files here"
],
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://platform.twitter.com https://staticxx.facebook.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

following is **init.js** which attaches the controller

```
export default class AddContactModule {
constructor() {
    // Check for the webpage we are currently in (linkedin, facebook, twitter, naukri, whatsapp, mail.google)
    this.currentHost = window.location.host.split('.');
    this.app = 'extension-extension';
    // Variable to intialize parent of button we will add
    this.globalButtonVar = '';
    this.copyglobalButtonVar = '';

    this.globalFormTemplate = '';
    this.globalForm = '';
    this.isLoggedin = false;

    // Get ng-app param and check if its already present if it is then no need to intialize angular module again
    this.ifAppDirective = document.querySelector('[ng-app]');

    console.log("hello1");
    this.init();
}

init() {
    this.eventHandling();
    this.addContactModel();
    this.checkHost();

}

// Function to set the flag to check if user is logged in or not
eventHandling() {
    if (!this.ifAppDirective && !$('.ng-scope').length) {
        // If ng-app is not initialized initialize ng-app
        $('body').attr('ng-app', this.app);

        this.miscellaneousEvent();
    }
}

// Function to call when user syncing images

// Function to handle other events
miscellaneousEvent() {
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu .input-group-btn, .dropdown-menu .checkbox, .dropdown-menu a', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Cancel the fetch list dialoge box
    $('body').on('click', '#fetchContainer-step2 > .innerContainer .close-fetch, .close-intro, .close-dialog', function() {
        let thisEle = $(this).attr('id');

        let scope = angular.element($('.pane.pane-three')).scope();
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.contact.cancelFetch(false, thisEle);
        });
    });

    // Close the notification of start sync message
    $('body').on('click', '#extension-close-notice', function(event) {
        let scope = angular.element($('#extension-close-notice')).scope();

        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.closeNotification();
        });
    });

    // If clicked on linkedin save button open call the trigger function to open contact details
    $('body').off('click', '#linkedin-save').on('click', '#linkedin-save', function() {
        let scope = angular.element($('#profile-wrapper')).scope();

        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.contact.linkedinFetch();
        });
    });

    // trigger save function for gmail
    $('body').off('click', '#gmail-save').on('click', '#gmail-save', function() {
        let scope = angular.element($('.nH.g.id')).scope();
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.gmailFetch();
        });
    });
}

// Function to handle addcontactmodel open/close events
addContactModel() {
    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '#addContactModal', function () {
        $(this).after('<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>');
    }).on('hide.bs.modal', '#addContactModal', function () {
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    });

    $('body').off('shown.bs.modal', '#addContactModal').on('shown.bs.modal', '#addContactModal', (event) => {
        let openedBy = $(event.relatedTarget);
        this.loginStatus();

        // Check for the target popup is opened by whatzup from group
        if(openedBy.hasClass('whatsappGroupBtn') || openedBy.hasClass('whatsappGroupChat')) {
            let contactObj = {
                ContactMobile: openedBy.data('contactnumber'),
                given: openedBy.data('name'),
                profilePic: openedBy.data('profilepic'),
            };

            // Reduce size of modal for group detail page
            if(openedBy.hasClass('whatsappGroupBtn')) {
                contactObj.addFrom = 'wa_group';
            } else {
                contactObj.addFrom = 'wa_chat';
            }

            // Assigne all found details to form, for this call controller function
            let scope = angular.element($('#addContactForm')).scope();
            // Set form to its default state
            scope.$apply(() => {
                scope.contact.updateForm(contactObj);
            });
        }

    }).off('hidden.bs.modal', '#addContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#addContactModal', () => {
        $('.arrowPointing').hide();

        // Assigne all found details to form, for this call controller function
        let scope = angular.element($('#addContactForm')).scope();
        // Set form to its default state
        scope.$apply(() => {
            scope.contact.addNewContact = false;
            // Helps to decide if the contact should be added to existing or new
            scope.contact.addtoExisting = false;
            scope.contact.noContact = false;
            // Contains searched contact list
            scope.contact.contactList = [];
            // Search field model, this will have the searching text
            scope.contact.searchKey = '';
            scope.contact.searchCompleted = false;
            scope.contact.globalTimeout = 0;

            //lets you add another unknown contact when one unknown already has been added
            scope.contact.contactAdded = false;
            scope.contact.contactSaved = false;
        });
    });
}

// Hide/show login arrow depends on the login status

// Depends on host call linkedin init or facebookinit
checkHost() {
    switch(this.currentHost[1]) {
        case 'linkedin': {
            this.initLinkedin();
            break;
        }
        case 'google': {
            this.initGmail();
            break;
        }
        case 'whatsapp': {
            this.initWhatsapp();
        } default: {}
    }
}
// Function to add template & button to linkedin
initLinkedin() {
    // Variable to check if the button we are adding is in extra info section or not
    let ifTablist = 1;
    let linkedinForm = ''; 
    // Button template if adding to extra info section
    let buttonTemplate = '<span class="inline-block extension-save-button"><button type="button" id="linkedin-save" class="secondary top-card-action link-without-visited-state"><img src="https://d73xd4ooutekr.cloudfront.net/v4/img/logo-42.png"> Save Contact</a></span>';
    let buttonContainerLength = 0;

    // Get the parent
    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', (event) => {
        if(event.target.id == 'profile-wrapper' && !buttonContainerLength) {
            this.globalButtonVar = this.copyglobalButtonVar = $('body').find('#profile-wrapper');

            buttonContainerLength = this.globalButtonVar.find('.pv-top-card-section__actions').length;

            // Check if the selected parent is not present 
            if(buttonContainerLength) {
                this.globalButtonVar.find('.pv-top-card-section__actions').append(buttonTemplate);
                this.setController();
            }
        }
    });
}
// Function to set ng-controller
setController() {
    if(this.globalButtonVar.length) {
        this.globalButtonVar.attr('ng-controller', 'ContactModalController as contact');
    }
}
}
```

following is the **controller.js** file

```
"use strict";
import AddContactModule from './init'

export default class ContactModalController {
constructor($scope, $compile) {
    // Intializing dependencies to the scope variable
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$compile = $compile;
    /* Assign required objects which need to make everything works */
    }


// Function to fetch linkedin details
linkedinFetch() {
    // Show more button, this will show all contact details of current user
    let saveBtn = $('.contact-see-more-less')

    if(saveBtn.attr('data-control-name') == 'contact_see_more') {
        saveBtn.click();
    }

    this.resetModal();

    this.grabContactDetails.getLinkedinDetails(this.$scope, (response) => {
        this.contactObj = response;
        // default selected List
        this.contactObj.selectedList = [];

        $('#addContactModal').modal('show');
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: For instance, it is not clear which context you are running in: content script, popup, etc. A complete [mcve] will inherently provide us that information from how the code is loaded.

Comment: Hello sir, I have updated the question and added expected behaviour column. And all this happening in Content Scripts. If you need more info. Please let me know. I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Came across a similar issue where the controller was not getting initialized.

I set the **app on the HTML tag** and set the **controller on body tag.**

The issue according to me is coming because of dynamic loading of DOM elements